# How to use CorelDRAW Type Library 17.0?

Tags: vb.net, membership, coreldraw

I'm trying to make an application to automate the creation of membership cards.

The idea would be to choose a template and a database, and the program generates a CorelDRAW file with all membership cards. A membership card per sheet.

But I dont know how to use the Library. How can I remplace text, import bitmaps, generate codebars, create new files and sheets in Corel using CorelDRAW Type Library 17.0?

Sorry for bad english..

Comment: CorelDRAW supports a number of addon technologies.  https://community.coreldraw.com/sdk/ has a lot of advice on how to get started.  You can create a DLL and can get access to the corel draw object model and do extensive operations.  Here is a tutorial on using the object model: https://community.coreldraw.com/sdk/w/guide/187.8-understanding-the-object-model

Answer (score -1):

First you have to import corel .tlb and .dll file in

```
C:\Program Files\Corel\CorelDRAW Graphics Suite X7\Programs64\CorelDraw.tlb
C:\Program Files\Corel\CorelDRAW Graphics Suite X7\Programs64\VGCore.dll
```

Imports CorelDRAW

Imports VGCore

**Second try this code. Make some changes**...

```
Private Sub abc_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles abc.Click
        Dim cdr As New VGCore.Application

        cdr.OpenDocument("C:\Users\User\Documents\file.cdr", 1)
        cdr.ActiveDocument.ExportBitmap("C:\Users\user\Desktop\newImage.png", CorelDRAW.cdrFilter.cdrPNG, CorelDRAW.cdrExportRange.cdrCurrentPage, CorelDRAW.cdrImageType.cdrRGBColorImage, 0, 0, _
         72, 72, CorelDRAW.cdrAntiAliasingType.cdrNoAntiAliasing, False, True, True, _
         False, CorelDRAW.cdrCompressionType.cdrCompressionNone, Nothing).Finish()
        cdr.ActiveDocument.Close()
        cdr.Quit()
    End Sub
```